# ActiveAdmin page not displaying form_tag form alongside other content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin page I want to use to upload a variety of files to various controllers:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Import" do
    content do
        columns do 
            column do
                panel "Overview" do
                    para "This is the admin Import page."
                end
            end
            column do
                panel "Update/Import Matters" do
                    para "This is some info about what this form should take."
                    form_tag import_matters_path, multipart: true do
                        file_field_tag :file
                        submit_tag "Import"
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The page displays, but the right hand column only displays the panel with the text "this is some info..." When I comment out that line, I get an import button but no way to upload a file.  When I comment out the submit_tag and the para line, I get the 'choose file' button to select a file to import, but nothing else.

The panel seems to be unable to concatenate the html from the form properly, but I'm not clear how to do that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a partial which seemed to fix the issue.  This ended up with the panel looking like this:

```
panel "Update/Import Matters" do
    para "Some info about the form."
    render 'matters_form'
end
```

And /app/views/admin/import/_matters_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag import_matters_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

This might not be the only way, but partials definitely worked in this situation.